# How do you scrape HTML content of a scrolled down page to the nth post on TikTok with Python Playwright?

Tags: python, scrollview, playwright, tiktok

**I want to scroll down to let's say at least until 72 posts is visible on a TikTok user page** such as [thebeatles page](https://www.tiktok.com/@thebeatles) **and then save the HTML content**. This page currently has 73 posts. I aimed to achieve the scrolling down with pressing the "End" key with `page.keyboard.press("End")` as long as the number of visible post is below 72 but only got back 30 posts. The fetching process aborts image and font requests for optimization. Below are the codes `test_fetch_raw_source.py` and `helper.py`, where the latter only contains functions for optimizations. **How do you scroll down to the nth, in this case 72nd, visible post?**

```
# test_fetch_raw_source.py
def test_fetch_front_page_with_n_latest_posts():
    # Fetch front page with n_count of visible posts
    usr = r"thebeatles"
    url = "".join([r"https://www.tiktok.com/@", usr])
    n = 72 # The most current posts count

    def get_visible_post_count(page):
        # Get visible post count
        post_urls = page.locator("//div[@data-e2e='user-post-item']//a")
        post_urls_count = len(post_urls.all())
        return post_urls_count

    def press_end(url_n):
        if not url_n:
            page.keyboard.press("End")

    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        browser = playwright.chromium.launch()
        context = browser.new_context()
        page = context.new_page()
        helper.logging_network_events(page)  # Logging

        # Abort requests
        helper.abort_image(page)
        helper.abort_image_by_ext(page)
        helper.abort_font_by_ext(page)
        
        # Get page
        page.goto(url, timeout=0)

        # If nth post element is not visible keep pressing key "End"
        url_n = page.locator("//div[@data-e2e='user-post-item']//a").nth(n-1).is_visible(timeout=0)
        for i in range(n):
            press_end(url_n)
        
        # Post count
        post_count = get_visible_post_count(page)
        print(post_count)

        # Save html
        usr_rel_path = "".join(["html/", usr, "/"])
        path_exists = os.path.exists(usr_rel_path)
        if not path_exists:
            os.makedirs(usr_rel_path)

        usr_folder = "".join([os.getcwd(), "/", usr_rel_path])
        file_name = "".join([usr, ".html"])
        file_dir = "".join([usr_folder, file_name])

        html_source = page.content()
        with open(file_dir, "w") as file:
            file.write(html_source)
            file.close()

        browser.close()


# helper.py
import re

def logging_network_events(page):
    # Logging network events
    page.on("request", lambda request: print(
        ">>", request.method, request.url,
        request.resource_type))
    page.on("response", lambda response: print(
        "<<", response.status, response.url))
def abort_image(page):
    page.route("**/*", lambda route: route.abort() if route.request.resource_type == "image" else route.continue_())
def abort_image_by_ext(page):
    page.route(re.compile("jpeg|jpg|png|tiff|gif"), lambda route: route.abort())
def abort_font_by_ext(page):
    page.route(re.compile("woff2|woff|otf"), lambda route: route.abort())
```

Answer (score 1):

In JS:

First define the locator for 'post' element and select the nth element

Scroll to this element

Verify its visible in the view.

```
const post = page.locator('postLocator').nth(75)
await post.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();
// Make sure at least some part of element intersects viewport.
await expect(post).toBeInViewport();
```

Reference:

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-be-in-viewport

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-nth

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by adding `page.wait_for_timeout(1000)` to the function `press_end()`, and `headless=False` to `playwright.chromium.launch()`:

```
def press_end():
    page.keyboard.press("End")
    page.wait_for_timeout(1000)

browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
```

And adding a check to whether the nth post is visible, and if not keep pressing the key "End" as follows:

```
n = 72
ini_post_count = get_visible_post_count(page)
current_url_max = page.locator("//div[@data-e2e='user-post-item']//a").nth(n - 1).is_visible()
for i in range(ini_post_count, n, ini_post_count):
    press_end()
    wait_current_max = page.locator("//div[@data-e2e='user-post-item']//a").nth(post_count - 1).wait_for()
    current_post_count = get_visible_post_count(page)
    if not current_post_count < n:
        break
```

For some reasons having to do with the server side security the scraping so far only works with `headless=False` mode, and it's crucial to add `page.wait_for_timeout(1000)` in order to wait for the posts to load after reaching the bottom of the page.